# Getting System Error during Paytm Payment Gateway implementation

Tags: php, android, payment-gateway, paytm

I am trying to implement paytm payment gateway rather tring to fetch balance api in of payment gateway. But I am getting Proper way to genrate tranasaction token and I am confused what should i do to link paytm wallet to my app. So anyone can Help me out to implement paytm wallet to my app and fetch balance and add balance into paytm wallet through my app.

I have tried [this](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/check-balance-api/) but I am not able get token and getting following error:

```
{"head":{"requestId":null,"responseTimestamp":"1582177808766","version":"v1"},"body":{"extraParamsMap":null,"resultInfo":{"resultStatus":"U","resultCode":"00000900","resultMsg":"System error"}}}
```

Comment: https://developer.paytm.com/docs/check-balance-api/ check this document.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with Initiate transaction API

Comment: Did you or @AdeebAbdulSalam solve this error? I am facing same error.

Comment: I am getting this with initiate transaction API. Any one fixed this?

Comment: Contact the developers, they replied to me immediately. But I didn't further check the result.